# NCommon - resources, documentation

Tags: c#, .net, ncommon

I like [NCommon](http://github.com/riteshrao/ncommon/) project, but the lack of resources and documentation makes it very hard to use.

Does anyone of you know some good resources, examples...?
I figured out some basic setting, like Repository Pattern etc. But i'm completly lost i.e. with "NCommon.Rules".

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NCommon author Ritesh Rao has sadly been very quiet for the past year. [His blog](http://www.codeinsanity.com/search/label/NCommon) is nevertheless an excellent resource for discussion of the rationale behinde (some of) the ideas in NCommon.

I agree that it's currently difficult to understand what all the clever stuff in the framework is really for since there's no sample app included in the source.

Ritesh did say a while back that he intended [Rhinestone](http://code.google.com/p/rhinestone/) to be a sample for NCommon but that never came to fruition. However, if you look [here](http://code.google.com/p/ncommon/issues/detail?id=8) you'll see that Ritesh is about to make a renewed effort to do a sample app and has started work on NCommon 1.1 (now on GitHub)

One final note of caution is that Ritesh has not tagged all of the pertinent posts in his blog with the NCommon tag because he started disussing some of the patterns he's used before he thought of rolling it all into NCommon so check his older posts also. For example he talks about implementing a [Persistence Ignorant Unit of Work](http://www.codeinsanity.com/2008/10/implementing-persistence-ignorant-unit.html) but didn't tag it with NCommon.

Comment: Thaks for resources. It helps me a lot. I hope Ritesh Rao puts demo app together soon.